# Heroku Undefined Table Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I just installed Heroku and trying to get my app running on it.

I get this error

```
2016-01-06T11:27:26.741740+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:47038
2016-01-06T11:27:26.741741+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-01-06T11:27:26.741741+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-01-06T11:27:26.741742+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 122.104.136.142 at 2016-01-06 11:27:26 +0000
2016-01-06T11:27:26.800681+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#home as HTML
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819306+00:00 app[web.1]:   Product Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819330+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819331+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819332+00:00 app[web.1]:                                   ^
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819332+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819793+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered products/_product_display.html.erb (5.4ms)
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819862+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered products/home.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
2016-01-06T11:27:26.819966+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms
```

I know my migrations are stuffed and if i drop the database i can't run `rake db:migrate` without getting the same error locally. So to get them to work i run `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` then `rake db:schema:load`. It loads the schema and `rake db:migrate` works.

Is there a way to load the schema in Heroku like i do locally? Or any other way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to run all of the same rake commands on Heroku as you do locally (assuming you've got the same code running at both ends).

Have you tried:

```
heroku run rake db:drop
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

or are you trying to fix it without dropping your heroku database or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the database on Heroku:

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm APP_NAME
```

then again Migrate the database:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku run rake db:reset` and then `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

This should work.